# Symfony wrong persist database working with two entity managers

Tags: symfony, entity, entitymanager

I have the same symfony app deployed in two servers. 
I use two entity managers, one called defaul with a connection on "local" database and the other called online on the "remote" database

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host%'
            port:     '%database_port%'
            dbname:   '%database_name%'
            user:     '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset:  UTF8
        online:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host2%'
            port:     '%database_port2%'
            dbname:   '%database_name2%'
            user:     '%database_user2%'
            password: '%database_password2%'
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            dql:
               string_functions:
                   GROUP_CONCAT: AppBundle\DQL\GroupConcatFunction
            connection: default
            mappings:
                LexikTranslationBundle: ~
                AppBundle:  ~
                LilWorksStoreBundle: ~
        online:
            connection: online
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
                LilWorksStoreBundle: ~
```

I copy some entities from the remote database to the local app within a service. My service get the two entity managers

```
services:
app.syncro:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Syncro
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager','@doctrine.orm.online_entity_manager']
```

I clone the remote entity and I try to persist it in my local

```
$user = $this->emRemote->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find(1);
$clonedUser = clone $user;
$this->emLocal->persist($clonedUser->cloneUser());
$this->emLocal->flush();
```

The flush don't persist in the local database but try to persist in the distant.

Is something in my configuration doesn't works? Maybe my entity still have the remote database name stored in proxy?

Comment: How does `User::cloneUser` method look like?

Comment: can we have your service constructor please ?

Comment: Maybe you should have an eye on it : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities